# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer JavaFX with Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm trying to debug my JavaFX maven project and getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules jsr305 and javax.annotation export package javax.annotation to module jline
```

I'm using maven and I also have a `module-info` file that looks like the following:

```
module com.test {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires kafka.clients;
    requires org.apache.avro;
    requires kafka.avro.serializer;
    requires kafka.streams.avro.serde;

    opens com.test;
    exports com.test;
}
```

I've tried adding excludes for the java annotation lib in the pom, to no avail. Still getting the same error. I also tried adding the javax annotation jar to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in IntelliJ but not with `maven` from command line, it run smoothly.

I managed to solve it in IntelliJ by removing some dependencies from IntelliJ classpath.

So `Open Module Settings`, module dependencies and I have removed:

[image: dependencies to remove in IntelliJ]

After that, the application started with no issue.

Hopefully this can help